# CTE vs Subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

need your help!

I've got a query in Postgres that I've written in 2 forms, one with a CTE and the other with the same query as the CTE mentioned but instead in a subquery. I need this to be able to run as a CTE because I re-use the table multiple times later one. The problem is that when i rewrite the same query as a CTE the query run time is over 5 minutes, whereas if it's in a subquery it runs in 5 seconds.

Runtime > 5 mins:

```
WITH test as (
  select 
    t.*, 
    case when (a.type in ('marketing','inventory') and a.created_at >= '2020-09-01') then a.subtype else 'classic' end as subtype
  from transactions t 
  left join accounts a on a.id=COALESCE(COALESCE(t.repays_account_id, t.funds_account_id), t.cashback_repays_account_id)
  ),


transactions_data as (
  select
    *
  from assets
  left join test t
    on t.business_id=a.business_id 
    and a.fund_date<= t.transaction_date
    and a.next_fund_date > t.transaction_date
    and t.type in ('payment','refund')
    and t.status in ('success','pending','failed')
    and a.subtype=t.subtype
)

select
  *
from transactions_data
```

Runs in 5 seconds:

```
  select
    *
  from assets
  left join (
      t.* 
      ,  case when (a.subtype in ('marketing','inventory') and a.created_at >= '2020-09-01') then a.subtype else 'classic' end as subtype
      from transactions t 
      left join accounts a on a.id=COALESCE(COALESCE(t.repays_account_id, t.funds_account_id), t.cashback_repays_account_id)
    ) t
    on t.business_id=a.business_id 
    and a.fund_date<= t.transaction_date
    and a.next_fund_date > t.transaction_date
    and t.type in ('payment','refund')
    and t.status in ('success','pending','failed')
    and a.subtype=t.subtype
```

Running explain on both

CTE:

```
Limit (cost=254637.74..254684.48 rows=2337 width=332)
```

Subquery:

```
Limit (cost=143463.64..143463.74 rows=5 width=332)
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

---

Thanks for the response guys, here's a similar example with the query plans. Appreciate your help!

**Query A**

```
explain analyse
select 
  t.*, 
  case when (a.subtype in ('marketing','inventory') and a.created_at >= '2020-09-01') then a.subtype else 'classic' end as subtype
from transactions t 
left join accounts a on a.id=COALESCE(t.repays_accounts_id, t.funds_accounts_id, t.cashback_repays_accounts_id)
```

Query Plan

```
1 Limit (cost=0.29..1978.08 rows=5000 width=998) (actual time=0.055..16.888 rows=5000 loops=1)
2 -> Nested Loop Left Join (cost=0.29..441848.45 rows=1117027 width=998) (actual time=0.055..16.530 rows=5000 loops...
3 -> Seq Scan on transactions t (cost=0.00..65010.27 rows=1117027 width=966) (actual time=0.011..0.866 rows=5...
4 -> Index Scan using accounts_pkey on accounts a (cost=0.29..0.33 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.002..0.002...
5 Index Cond: (id = COALESCE(t.repays_accounts_id, t.funds_accounts_id, t.cashback_repays_accounts_id))
6 Planning Time: 0.927 ms
7 Execution Time: 17.186 ms
```

**Query B**

```
explain analyse
WITH test as (
    select 
      t.*, 
      case when (a.subtype in ('marketing','inventory') and a.created_at >= '2020-09-01') then a.subtype else 'classic' end as subtype
    from transactions t 
    left join accounts a on a.id=COALESCE(t.repays_accounts_id, t.funds_accounts_id, t.cashback_repays_accounts_id)
  )

select
  *
from test
```

Query Plan

```
1 Limit (cost=81510.44..81610.44 rows=5000 width=821) (actual time=47.760..60.290 rows=5000 loops=1)
2 CTE test
3-> Hash Left Join (cost=7982.64..81510.44 rows=1117027 width=998) (actual time=47.751..53.021 rows=5000 loops=1...
4 Hash Cond: (COALESCE(t.repays_accounts_id, t.funds_accounts_id, t.cashback_repays_accounts_id) = a.id)
5 -> Seq Scan on transactions t (cost=0.00..65010.27 rows=1117027 width=966) (actual time=0.040..0.888 rows...
6 -> Hash (cost=7225.06..7225.06 rows=60606 width=19) (actual time=47.421..47.421 rows=60996 loops=1)
7 Buckets: 65536 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 3627kB
8 -> Seq Scan on advances a (cost=0.00..7225.06 rows=60606 width=19) (actual time=0.011..35.030 rows=...
9 -> CTE Scan on test (cost=0.00..22340.54 rows=1117027 width=821) (actual time=47.759..59.923 rows=5000 loops=1)
10 Planning Time: 0.569 ms
11 Execution Time: 60.819 ms
```

I'm not good with reading query plan but there's clearly a significant difference, is there any way to use the CTE without such a dramatic hit to performance? I'm assuming it's because i lose the indexing?

Comment: I don't see the CTE used more than once. Without seeing your real query, I cannot suggest improvements.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) for both queries generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Alternatively you can upload them to https://explain.depesz.com

Comment: A bit unrelated, but COALESCE can take more than two arguments.  I don't think you need two separate COALESCE functions in your join condition.

Comment: I would guess that the CTE is materialized, losing indexes for the rest of the query.

Comment: Appreciate the response guys! Editted the main ask.

Comment: Does the query optimizer exclude indexes when articles are embedded in CTE's? That would jump out as an issue because you only exercised the CTE once, the same as if it were a subquery, odd.

Comment: I don't understand why your CTE version first generates a full `test` table, then generates a joined `transactions_data` table, and then selects from `transactions_data`. Why do you need the interim `transactions_data` reference?  Just do the join from `accounts` directly to your `with test as...` CTE.

Comment: In my expierence, CTE's and Subqueries "generally" use the same query plan when exercised the same number of times.

Comment: Hey @Marc this is a typo on my end, in the CTE version from `transactions_data` this should be joining to another table called assets, and in latter parts of the query the transactional data in `test` would join to other tables. I just can't grasp why the CTE version is so drastically more costly to run